# `tensorflow_io.bigquery` returns `Empty update [Op:IO>BigQueryReadSession]` error

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, tensorflow-datasets

I'm following this [end to end example for BigQuery TensorFlow reader](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/bigquery) on my Mac laptop, but when I run the following line

```
read_session = tensorflow_io_bigquery_client.read_session(...)
```

I get the following error

```
E0504 17:14:36.436042000 4592741888 ssl_utils.cc:463]                  load_file: {"created":"@1620173676.435988000","description":"Failed to load file","file":"external/com_github_grpc_grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/load_file.cc","file_line":71,"filename":"/usr/share/grpc/roots.pem","referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1620173676.435986000","description":"No such file or directory","errno":2,"file":"external/com_github_grpc_grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/load_file.cc","file_line":45,"os_error":"No such file or directory","syscall":"fopen"}]}
E0504 17:14:36.436075000 4592741888 ssl_security_connector.cc:420]     Could not get default pem root certs.
E0504 17:14:36.436086000 4592741888 secure_channel_create.cc:132]      Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'bigquerystorage.googleapis.com'
E0504 17:14:36.436098000 4592741888 secure_channel_create.cc:50]       Failed to create channel args during subchannel creation.
E0504 17:14:36.436142000 4592741888 ssl_security_connector.cc:420]     Could not get default pem root certs.
E0504 17:14:36.436152000 4592741888 secure_channel_create.cc:132]      Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'bigquerystorage.googleapis.com'
E0504 17:14:36.436161000 4592741888 secure_channel_create.cc:50]       Failed to create channel args during subchannel creation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 32, in <module>
  File "/Users/someuser/.virtualenvs/py36-tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_io/bigquery/python/ops/bigquery_api.py", line 134, in read_session
    row_restriction=row_restriction)
  File "<string>", line 1093, in io_big_query_read_session
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnavailableError: Error reading from Cloud BigQuery: Empty update [Op:IO>BigQueryReadSession]
```

On the same machine if I create a container and install the same dependencies with the same versions, the example code runs with no problems. Any ideas what this error means, what may be causing it, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scene, BigQuery client is using gRPC to stream the data.

On Windows and macOS, gRPC requires an environment variable to find the root of trust for SSL, which is probably already included in the container that you built.

You can [install the certificate manually](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/main/google/cloud/bigtable/examples/README.md#configure-environment) to fix the issue.